# The Hessian matrix of $f$ is the zero matrix at a point. Can I move away and get non-zero matrix?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$
be a twice differentiable function, 
and let $H(\mathbf{x})$ denote the Hessian matrix of $f$ at $\mathbf{x}$. 
Suppose at $\mathbf{x}_0$, $H(\mathbf{x}_0)$ is the zero matrix.

I would like to prove the following: Suppose the Hessian of $f$ is not an identically zero matrix (i.e. not all entries are identically zero) when restricted to any open subset. For any $\varepsilon > 0$ there exist $|\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}_0| < \varepsilon$ such that $H(\mathbf{x})$ is not a zero matrix.

Ay comments would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Suppose $f$ is constant on a ball centered at $\mathbf x_0$, but varies outside that ball. (You can easily arrange a smooth function like this using famous techniques.)

Comment: Thanks for point this out, I actually  wanted to avoid these situations. Let me fix the question.

Comment: The stronger assumption that you edited into the question seems to include the answer. $H$ is not identically zero on the open ball of radius $\varepsilon$ around $\mathbf x_0$.

Comment: You've turned this completely into a non-question. A slightly more interesting question still remains: If $f$ is non-constant on a ball centered at $\mathbf x_0$, can you conclude that the Hessian is not identically zero on that ball? And the answer to that is ... ?

Answer (score 1):

I find the question quite weird but well...

The ball $B_\varepsilon(\mathbf x_0) = \{\mathbf y \in\Bbb R^n: |\mathbf y - \mathbf x_0|<\varepsilon\}$ is an open set. By your assumption, we can find $\mathbf x\in B_\varepsilon(\mathbf x_0)$ such that $H(\mathbf x)\ne \mathbf 0$. The fact that $|\mathbf x - \mathbf x_0|<\varepsilon$ follows pretty much from the definition of ball.